# How to apply a delayed job or background process in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, backgroundworker

I have created a Rails app which uploads a video to a Box account. All works fine when a video is small sized video. However, when video is a big file, I get c9.io's bad gateway error. To avoid this, I wanna add a background process which will upload the video for me, as I have no issue with Box's API's session.

Comment: There a number of gems that make that process fairly easy, for example [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v4.1.2), [sideqik](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). Take a look at them and choose the one that best fits your project.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try these options and let you know if any issue arises .